# Website pages with slashes

Tags: .htaccess, web

Just building a site using php.  I would like to know how to create pages without having to make ".php" links for every page.  For example I want to build the site to be as follows:  www.mysite.com/products instead of www.mysite.com/products.php.  (Further example www.mysite.com/products/headphones )

An example of what I am looking for is as follows: http://www.starbucks.ca/store-locator

Any idea how starbucks is doing this?  It isn't making a separate folder and index for every page is it?

Thanks in advance!

Jason

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL rewriting to do this. You can create a `.htaccess` file, place it in the root directory of your website with the following content (as an example):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tutorial/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?tutorial=$1
RewriteRule ^page/store-locator/$ index.php?page=store-locator
RewriteRule ^$ index.php
```

These are some basic rules that tell the web server to rewrite a URL without `.php` to a URL that does have `.php`.

In the above example, when you are visiting example.com/tutorial/3/, it will actually visit example.com/index.php?tutorial=3 and then your index.php will display the contents. It's similar for the store-locator page.